# regarding pattern

Tags: 14.04, command-line

As i am new to ubuntu i stuck in a place. how can i get a particular pattern from my terminal and can save to any file like .txt file or any libre office file.
file looks like:-

```
[Dec 17 00:00:07] [302134] [snapdeal-suggest] [info] - Initial query: lg e975
[Dec 17 00:00:07] [302134] [snapdeal-suggest] [info] - Input query: lg, Spell-corrected query: lg e975, NumSuggestions: 0, Time taken: 70 microseconds
```

and i want to save this in following format:

```
  TIME STAND               Initial query                      NumSuggestions
[Dec 17 00:00:07]             lg e975                            0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure whether that option is available. But I can suggest you a solution. You can write the output(the data you have quoted) of the terminal into a libre office text file and perform filter of the necessary details you need in the software. To write the output of terminal to text you can check this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32070/how-to-write-terminal-contents-into-a-file)